# How to retrieve user role(s) in oxwall?

Tags: oxwall

I can retrieve some very basic data with:

```
OW::getUser()->getUserObject()
```

But I have no idea how to retrieve roles an user belongs to. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the authorisation service class. See example below:

```
// list user roles of currently logged in user
$userId = OW::getUser()->getId(); // get current user Id
BOL_AuthorizationService::getInstance()->findUserRoleList($userId); // list user roles
```